# Building layer wise model for Encoding-Decoding Image

Tags: image-processing, autoencoder, chainer

I am writing an autoencoder model for an image encoding-decoding problem.
I want to understand the node distribution in each layer of the model suitable for images.

For the below code I am using 10 images of shape (21*28*3).

```
class Autoencoder(Chain):
  def __init__(self, activation=F.relu):
    super().__init__()
    with self.init_scope():
  # encoder part
      self.l1 = L.Linear(1764,882)
      self.l2 = L.Linear(882,441)
  # decoder part
      self.l3 = L.Linear(441,882)
      self.l4 = L.Linear(882,1764)
      self.activation = activation

  def forward(self,x):
      h = self.encode(x)
      x_recon = self.decode(h)
      return x_recon

  def __call__(self,x):
      x_recon = self.forward(x)
      loss = F.mean_squared_error(h, x)
      return loss

  def encode(self, x):
      h = F.dropout(self.activation(self.l1(x)))
      return self.activation(self.l2(x))

  def decode(self, h, train=True):
      h = self.activation(self.l3(h))
      return self.l4(x)

gpu_id = 0
n_epoch = 5
batch_size = 2

model = Autoencoder()

optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05).setup(model)
train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(xs,batch_size)
valid_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(xs,batch_size)

updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter,optimizer)
trainer = training.Trainer(updater,(n_epoch,"epoch"),out="result")

from chainer.training import extensions
trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(valid_iter, model, device=gpu_id))
```

While running trainer.run():

```
InvalidType: 
Invalid operation is performed in: LinearFunction (Forward)
Expect: x.shape[1] == W.shape[1]
Actual: 1764 != 882
```

I want to understand how node distribution works layer wise in a model. Please suggest any resource. Also how to assign nodes in layers in case of small number of training images.

Comment: The second line of `def encode` should use `h` instead of `x` to resolve the InvalidType error.

Comment: Using h as in h = F.dropout(self.activation(self.l1(h))) gives the error: 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'h' referenced before assignment when trying to train.